# Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Bar

Tags: python, plotly

I'm creating an api web call to pull data and outputting the results to a bar chart using Plotly. I'm getting 'Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Bar'

```
#python_repos_visual.py
from plotly.graph_objs import Bar
from plotly import offline
import requests

#Make an api call and store the response
url = ('https://api.github.com/search'
'/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars')
headers = {'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(f"Status code: {r.status_code}")

#Process results
response_dict = r.json()
repo_dicts = response_dict['items']
repo_names, stars = [], []
for repo_dict in repo_dicts:
    repo_names.append(repo_dict['name'])
    stars.append(repo_dict['stargazers_count'])

#Make visualization.
data = [{
    'type': 'bar',
    'x': repo_names,
    'y:': stars,
}]

my_layout = {
    'title': 'Most starred Python Projects on GitHub',
    'xaxis': {'title': 'Repository'},
    'yaxis': {'title': 'Stars'},
}
fig = {'data': data, 'layout': my_layout}
offline.plot(fig, filename='python_repos.html')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should change the import and keep in mind that `plotly` is offline only from version 4.0.

```py
# Change your imports to
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import requests

# Make Visualization
trace = go.Bar(x=repo_names, y=stars)
my_layout = {
    'title': 'Most starred Python Projects on GitHub',
    'title_x': 0.5,
    'xaxis': {'title': 'Repository'},
    'yaxis': {'title': 'Stars'},
}

fig = go.Figure(data=trace, layout=my_layout)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer @rpanai, if I needed to output this as "div" so I could carry over to my html page, where would I put that "output_type" argument in?

Comment: Had I waited just a few more seconds and another few tries I would have had my answer. created another var "final_plot = plot(fig, output_type='div')" thanks again for the answer!